# Which intermolecular interaction is dependent on the inverse cube of distance?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond, dipole

> The intermolecular interaction that is dependent on the inverse cube of distance between molecules is:
>
> 1. hydrogen bond
> 2. ion-ion interaction
> 3. ion-dipole interaction
> 4. London force

Inverse cube of distance I think means an ion-dipole interaction, since we know force due to a dipole on a charge is inversely proportional to the cube of distance. But I don't understand why the answer given is hydrogen bond. What is the distance dependence of the hydrogen bond? Shouldn't the answer be (3)?

Answer (score 7):

### 2

The ion-ion or charge-charge interaction is given by

$$
V_{\text{cc}} = \frac{Z_{i}Z_{j}e^{2}}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{R}_{i} - \mathbf{R}_{j}|}
$$

and is therefore proportional to $R^{-1}$.

### 3

The ion-dipole or charge-(permanent) dipole interaction is given by

$$
V_{\text{cd}} = \frac{Z_{i}e}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}} \frac{\mathbf{R}_{ij} \cdot \vec{\mu}_{j}}{R_{ij}^{3}}
$$

and is therefore proportional to $R^{-2}$.

### 4

"London force" is often meant to encapsulate any of the [van der Waals forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) ([here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/60619/194), [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48787/194)), but in particular the dispersion force. All of the above have a $R^{-6}$ dependence.

---

Here is a [general table](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/states/interact.html) that covers each of the interactions so far:

\begin{array}{lll}
\hline
\text{type of molecular unit} & \text{type of force} & n~\text{in}~R^{-n} \\
\hline
\text{ions}                        & \text{coulombic}               & 1 \\
\text{ion - polar molecule}        & \text{ion - dipole}            & 2 \\
\text{two polar molecules}         & \text{dipole - dipole}         & 3 \\
\text{ion - nonpolar molecule}     & \text{ion - induced dipole}    & 4 \\
\text{polar and nonpolar molecule} & \text{dipole - induced dipole} & 6 \\
\text{nonpolar molecules}          & \text{dispersion}              & 6 \\
\hline
\end{array}

### 1

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_bond):

> The hydrogen bond is often described as an [electrostatic dipole-dipole interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole-dipole_interaction). However, it also has some features of [covalent bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond): it is directional and strong, produces interatomic distances shorter than the sum of the van der Waals radii, and usually involves a limited number of interaction partners, which can be interpreted as a type of [valence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_(chemistry)). These covalent features are more substantial when acceptors bind hydrogens from more electronegative donors.

This implies that hydrogen bonding interactions may not behave exactly as $R^{-3}$. Consider the water dimer:

[image]

which is a prototypical example of a hydrogen-bonded complex. From Stone, using density functional-based symmetry-adapted perturbation theory (SAPT-DFT) in the aug-cc-pVQZ basis,
\begin{array}{lr}
\hline
\text{Type of interaction} & \text{Energy (kJ/mol)} \\
\hline
\text{Electrostatic}                 & -33.4 \\
\text{Exchange-repulsion}            &  31.5 \\
\text{Dispersion}                    & -12.2 \\
\text{Induction}                     &  -8.0 \\
\text{Charge transfer}               &  -5.9 \\
\text{Exchange-dispersion}           &   2.3 \\
\text{Exchange-induction}            &   7.8 \\
\delta_{\text{HF}}~\text{correction} &  -3.4 \\
\hline
\text{Total}                         & -21.5 \\
\hline
\end{array}
the electrostatic component is clearly the largest contributor, but after taking the absolute value of all interaction terms, is about 32% of the total interaction. Another approach for decomposing the interaction energy is based on absolutely localized molecular orbitals (ALMO-EDA), which at the $\omega$B97M-V/def2-QZVPP level gives
\begin{array}{lr}
\hline
\text{Type of interaction} & \text{Energy (kJ/mol)} \\
\hline
\text{Electrostatics}  & -65.7 \\
\text{Pauli repulsion} &  65.0 \\
\text{Dispersion}      &  -7.7 \\
\text{Polarization}    &  -4.6 \\
\text{Charge transfer} &  -7.9 \\
\hline
\text{Total}           & -20.9 \\
\hline
\end{array}
SAPT-DFT and ALMO-EDA are in good agreement, though charge transfer is more important in ALMO-EDA primarily due to the lackluster definition of charge transfer within SAPT. Electrostatics are now about 44% of the total interaction. For reference, here is how the additional terms decay (Stone, Table 1.2):
\begin{array}{lccl}
\hline
\text{Contribution} & \text{Additive?} & \text{Sign} & \text{Comment} \\
\hline
\textbf{Long-range}~(U \sim R^{-n}) & & & \\
\text{Electrostatic} & \text{Yes}     & \pm & \text{Strong orientation dependence} \\
\text{Induction}     & \text{No}      & -   &                                      \\
\text{Dispersion}    & \text{approx.} & -   & \text{Always present}                \\
\text{Resonance}     & \text{No}      & \pm & \text{Degenerate states only}        \\
\text{Magnetic}      & \text{Yes}     & \pm & \text{Very small}                    \\
\hline
\textbf{Short-range}~(U \sim e^{-\alpha R}) & & & \\
\text{Exchange-repulsion}  & \text{approx.} & + & \text{Dominates at very short range} \\
\text{Exchange-induction}  & \text{approx.} & - &                                      \\
\text{Exchange-dispersion} & \text{approx.} & - &                                      \\
\text{Charge transfer}     & \text{No}      & - & \text{Donor-acceptor interaction}    \\
\hline
\end{array}

### Answer

Although components of hydrogen bonding interactions may have a $R^{-3}$ distance dependence, there are significant contributors to the hydrogen bond interaction other than electrostatics that do not decay as $R^{-3}$; in general, it is a complex interaction and its definition is still hotly debated. For that reason, the *best* answer is (3), the ion-dipole interaction.

### References

- [Masahiro Yamamoto, Kyoto University: charge-charge, charge-dipole, dipole-charge, dipole-dipole interaction](https://janheyda.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/electrostatics-multipoles.pdf)
- [Stephen Lower, Simon Fraser University: Chem1 Virtual Textbook, Interactions between Molecular Units](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/states/interact.html)
- [Anthony Stone: The Theory of Intermolecular Forces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198789157)
- ALMO-EDA calculations: geometry is B97-D/def2-TZVP, EDA input as comment

Answer (score 1):

Simple Google search led me to the content at [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermolecular_force):

> The energy of a Keesom interaction depends on the inverse sixth power of the distance, unlike **the interaction energy of two spatially fixed dipoles, which depends on the inverse third power of the distance.**

Comment: so this ion-dipole interaction comes under which one exctly?? keesom interactiom?? or two fixed dipoles?? i thought it comes under the interaction between a charge and a dipole in space

Comment: This answer does not seem to fit any of the given options.

Comment: @GaurangTandon only if hydrogen bond is considered dipole-dipole interaction...